# TypeScript/JavaScript forEach call

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble understanding this bit of code:

```
stringsArray.forEach(s => {
    for (var name in validators) {
        console.log('"' + s + '" ' +
            (validators[name].isAcceptable(s) ?
                ' matches ' : ' doesnt match ') + name);
    }
});
```

in particular, the `s => { ...` part is mysterious. It looks like s is being assigned to the next string in the array on each loop. But what is the `=>` part meaning? It's related to lambdas I think, but I am not following.

Answer (score 16):

Yeah it's a lambda (for example, similar to ECMAScript6 and Ruby, as well as some other languages.)

`Array.prototype.forEach` takes three arguments, `element, index, array`, so `s` is just the parameter name being used for `element`.

It'd be like writing this in regular ECMAScript5:

```
stringsArray.forEach(function(s) {
    for (var name in validators) {
        console.log('"' + s + '" ' +
            (validators[name].isAcceptable(s) ?
                ' matches ' : ' doesnt match ') + name);
    }
});
```

In the above example, you didn't show the whole code, so I assume `validators` is just a plain object `{}`.

The syntax for the example you gave is actually identical to the ES6 syntax.

Check out this example from [the TypeScript handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook):

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks... Still a little confused... Note that I am quite proficient in Ruby but not in JS. I am learning TS instead because it seems like a more solid foundation for me... is "s => { }" passing a lambda as the first argument to for_each? If so, how can s appear again in the body of the lambda itself? That's where I am stumped (for now.) Thanks!

Comment: @pitosalas, TypeScript is icing on top of JavaScript. I think it's probably a bad idea to learn TypeScript first, and not the other way around. Have you read the documentation for `.forEach`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: well I know a little js (and I am reading eloquent js in parallel) so other than some trickiness here I feel pretty comfortable. But I will follow the link you point to and study that too. Thanks.